# Boost MSM only processing internal transitions

Tags: c++, boost, state-machine, boost-msm

I'm using the new Boost 1.44.0 MSM library to produce a state machine. In this state machine there are two classes of events `class1` and `class2`. `class1` events can be processed by either states `S1` or `S2` while `class2` events can only be processed by state `S2`.

A special `class1` event `upgrade_req` requests an upgrade from state `S1` to state `S2`.

I've implemented that in Boost::MSM as follows:

```
// State S1 and S2 allow any class1 events
struct class1 {};
// Only state S2 allows class2 events
struct class2 {};

// an upgrade request is a class1 event that requests an upgrade to state 2
struct upgrade_req : public class1 {};

struct MyFSM : public msm::front::state_machine_def< MyFSM >
{
    /// State 1. Allows any class1 event
    struct S1 : public msm::front::state<>
    {
        /// functor says "processing event in State 1"
        struct ProcessEvent { /* ... */ };

        struct internal_transition_table : mpl::vector<
            //        Event   Action        Guard
            //       +-------+-------------+------------+
            Internal< class1, ProcessEvent, none >
        > {};
    }; // S1

    /// State 2. Allows any class1 or class2 events
    struct S2 : public msm::front::state<>
    {
        /// functor says "processing event in State 2"
        struct ProcessEvent { /* ... */ };

        struct internal_transition_table : mpl::vector<
            //        Event   Action        Guard
            //       +-------+-------------+------------+
            Internal< class1, ProcessEvent, none >,
            Internal< class2, ProcessEvent, none >
        > {};
    }; // S2

    /// everybody starts in state 1
    typedef S1 initial_state;

    /// send an error if a class2 event was received for state1
    struct SendError { /* ... */ };

    /// Send a response to the upgrade request
    struct SendUpgradeRsp { /* ... */ };

    /// functor returns true if the request to upgrade to state 2 is OK.
    struct VerifyUpgradeReq { /* ... */ };

    struct transition_table : mpl::vector<
        //  Start  Event         Next   Action           Guard
        // +------+-------------+------+----------------+------------------+
        Row< S1,   class1,       none,  none,            none,
        Row< S1,   class2,       S1,    SendError,       none >,
        Row< S1,   upgrade_req,  S2,    SendUpgradRsp,   VerifyUpgradeReq >,

        Row< S2,   class1,       none,  none,            none,
        Row< S2,   class2,       none,  none,            none >
    > {};
}; // MyFSM
```

My problem is that when I use this as it is, the `upgrade_req` event is never processed by the main `MyFSM::transition_table`. It is only processed by the `S1::internal_transition_table`.

For example:

```
int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    msm::back::state_machine< MyFSM > sm;
    sm.start();
    sm.process_event( class1() );
    sm.process_event( upgrade_req() ); 
    sm.process_event( class2() );
    return 0;
}
```

I would desire the output of this to be:

> processing event in State 1.
>   Upgrade Request OK.
>   processing event in State 2.

But, what I get is this:

> processing event in State 1.
>   processing event in State 1.
>   Error. Received class 2 event in State 1.

Does anybody have a suggestion on how I can fix this issue?

Thanks,
PaulH

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that the priority of internal transitions is higher than those defined in the transition table. And update_req being a class1, the internal transiton fires. This is actually conform to the UML standard.
MSM offers you a second solution, you can define S1's internal transition with a Row with none as target inside transition_table instead of using an internal_transition_table. If you define it BEFORE the transition S1 + upgrade_reg -> S2, it will have a lesser prio and will be tried only if the other one cannot be considered.

If you absolutely need an internal_transition_table then you can only provide a guard to reject class1 if it's not an update_req.

HTH,
Christophe Henry

PS: I only found this post by luck. Posting to the boost user list will guarantee you a much faster answer.